# stlport_shared.so not getting pushed onto the device

Tags: android-ndk-r5

I am defining Application.mk
APP_STL := stlport_shared

When I run ndk-build which in turn producing file: stlport_shared.so in obj/local/armeabi/
but it is not copying this file to libs/armeabi/
Because of which it doesn't get copied to the device and 
System.loadLibrary() throws UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be mentioned in the Application.mk as:
APP_MODULES := stlport_shared.so other_dependent.so

In ordered to be copied to the device.

Comment: It should be Without the `.so` prefix, though.

Comment: Make sure to include your other modules too if you add this directive.  However Android Studio seems to still install libstlport_shared.so into the appropriate folders under libs, even without this directive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include something like following in your Android.mk file:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := stlport_shared  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := stlport_shared.so  
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a line to my java file to load it:

```
System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
System.loadLibrary("my_lib");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nishant said, you need to use:

```
APP_STL       := stlport_shared
APP_MODULES   := stlport_shared mymodule ...
```

`APP_STL` ensures use of STLport, while `APP_MODULES` ensures its copied where needed.

Its a bug that `stlport_shared` is not copied as needed. See Android Issue 21180: [APP_STL := stlport_shared doesn't install libstlport_shared.so into libs directory](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21180). It should be fixed in NDK R7b.